# Proper Routing - Help Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2

I am using zend pagination in my gallery and its unfortunetly not working right for me.

When using tags and search box in **gallery** -> **next/another** page is returning with no **taging/searching**

It should look like this:

```
gallery\page\2\?s=&tag=9
```

but instead I have this:

```
gallery\page\2
```

What can I do about that?

```
'gallery' => array(
    'type' => 'Segment',
        'options' => array(
            'route' => '/generator_nowy/gallery[/page/:page/]',
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'Men\Controller\FrontController',
                'action' => 'gallery',
                'page' => 1,
            )
        ),
'may_terminate' => true
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
'gallery' => array(
  'type' => 'Segment',
  'options' => array(
    'route' => '/generator_nowy/gallery[/page/:page/]',
    'defaults' => array(
       'controller' => 'Men\Controller\FrontController',
       'action' => 'gallery',
       'page' => 1,
    )
  ),
  'may_terminate' => true,
  'child_routes'  => array(
    'query' => array(
      'type' => 'Query',
    ),
  ),
),
```